# Failed to claim interface: Operation not supported or unimplemented on this platform

Tags: google-chrome, barcode, barcode-scanner, webusb

I'm trying to use a USB Barcode Scanner on Windows 10 in Chrome `v73.0.3683.86` via WebUSB.

The scanner is a `Honeywell Voyager 1250g`.

I can see the device via the device dialog - I can also open it and select a configuration.

However, when I try to claim `interface(1)`  (There are 3 interfaces, but 1 is the bulk transfer) I get the error `Failed to claim interface: Operation not supported or unimplemented on this platform` in `chrome://device-log/`.

Is there a way around this, or is this scanner just not usable via WebUSB? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried connecting to this device using WebUSB on other platforms? Windows has a particular additional requirement for applications (like Chrome) to access USB devices which is that the WinUSB.sys driver must be loaded for the interface.

I've written an article explaining the particular requirements on Windows here: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/native-hardware/build-for-webusb/#windows

If you use the Windows Device Manager you can check which drivers are loaded for your device. If there is no driver loaded then you may be able to write a custom INF file as described in that article to instruct Windows to load the driver you want.

Comment: I haven't tried other platforms (I'd have to find a non-Windows device to do so), but I am already running the WinUSB driver for the device by setting it via Zadig.